# how to downgrade React-Native version in EXPO app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

how can i downgrade react-native verion in my expo app : i have this version :

```
npm view react-native version
0.64.1
```

and i need to make it 62. this is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
}
```

i tryed this npm install react-native@0.62 but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install --save react-native@0.62` , but it won't work

If you have managed expo app you can't change that version, expo is using fork of react-native and specific version is hard-coded for every sdk. If you just change it in package.json and run `expo build:android`/`expo build:ios` it will build javascript bundle using that react-native, but native code will be still from old react-native, which likely is not compatible.

To change version of react-native you need to either:

- eject
- downgrade to earlier expo sdk (but it will go out of support earlier, so I'm not recommending that)

Comment: can i create a new expo app and choose specefic version while creating ?

Comment: you can create new app that is using older expo sdk, but you can't specify version of react-native. Expo builders have one prebuild app for every sdk, only part you have control over is content of app.json and javascript (your code and libraries you are using), everything else e.g. native code for react-native and other libraries is fixed and every app build on specific sdk is shipping with the same exact binaries

Answer (score 0):

Just update the package which you want to use. And then run the following commands:

```
npm uninstall react-native
npm install react-native
```

It will now install the package as defined in the `package.json` file. Notice, I have not used `--save` argument because we're already having it in `package.json`.

And as per the changes, you may have to replace some code where newer version code appears.